# React select values not remaining selected

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a select dropdown that onChange updates all the select dropdowns in the table.

State is being set correctly. However when I change any of the selects in the table the value does not remain selected (displayed).

It sets state correctly fro both children and master selects. Its just not displaying the option selected.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    // import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    // import { Select } from 'element-react';

    import Select from 'react-select';
    import logo from './logo.svg';
    import './App.css';

    class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
        products: [],
        categories: [],
        filterText: '',
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleFilterTextChange = this.handleFilterTextChange.bind(this);
        this.masterCategoryChange = this.masterCategoryChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleFilterTextChange(filterText) {
        this.props.handleFilterTextChange(filterText)
        this.setState({
        filterText: filterText
        });
    }

    handleChange(product, index, e){
        product.category_id  = e.value;
        let selectValues = this.state.selectValues;
        selectValues[index] = e.value;
        this.setState({selectValues});
    }

    masterCategoryChange(e){
        let selectValues = this.state.selectValues;
        selectValues.forEach(function(sv, index) {
        selectValues[index] = e.value;
        });
        console.log(selectValues)
        this.setState({selectValues});
    }

    /* Inside your component */
    componentDidMount() {
        const apiRequest = url => fetch(url).then(response => response.json())

        const apiRequestProducts = () => {
            return apiRequest("http://docker.for.mac.localhost:4000/api/products?filter[limit]=5").then(function(response) {
                return response;
            });
        };

        const apiRequestCategories = () => {
            return apiRequest("http://docker.for.mac.localhost:4000/api/categories?filter[limit]=7").then(function(response) {
                return response;
            });
        };

        this.setState({loading: true});

        Promise.all([
            apiRequestProducts(),
            apiRequestCategories()
        ]).then(results => {
            var selectValues = [];
            for (var i=0; i < results[0].length; i++) {
                selectValues[i] = '';
            }
            this.setState({
                selectValues,
                products: results[0],
                categories: results[1],
                loading: false
            });
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log('Oops, something went wrong', err);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
            </header>
            <FilterableProductTable 
            masterCategoryChange={this.masterCategoryChange}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            products={this.state.products} 
            categories={this.state.categories}
            filterText={this.state.fliterText}
            categorySelectValues={this.state.selectValues}
            />
        </div>
        );
    }
    }

    class FilterableProductTable extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.handleFilterTextChange = this.handleFilterTextChange.bind(this);
        this.handleCategoryChange = this.handleCategoryChange.bind(this);
        this.handleMasterCategoryChange = this.handleMasterCategoryChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleFilterTextChange(filterText) {
        this.props.handleFilterTextChange(filterText)
    }

    handleCategoryChange(product, index, e){
        this.props.handleChange(product, index, e)
    }

    handleMasterCategoryChange(e){
        this.props.masterCategoryChange(e)
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <SearchBar
            filterText={this.props.filterText}
            onFilterTextChange={this.handleFilterTextChange}
            />
            <ProductTable
            handleMasterCategoryChange={this.handleMasterCategoryChange}
            handleCategoryChange={this.handleCategoryChange}
            handleFilterTextChange={this.handleFilterTextChange}
            products={this.props.products}
            categories={this.props.categories}
            filterText={this.props.filterText}
            selectValues={this.props.categorySelectValues}
            />
        </div>
        );
    }
    }
    class ProductTable extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.onProductCategoryChange = this.onProductCategoryChange.bind(this);
        this.masterCategoryChange = this.masterCategoryChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        console.log('this is:', this);
    }

    onProductCategoryChange(product, index, e){
        this.props.handleCategoryChange(product, index, e)

    }

    masterCategoryChange(e){
        this.props.handleMasterCategoryChange(e)
    }

    render() {
        console.log('Rendering');
        console.log(this.props.selectValues);

        let options = this.props.categories.map(function (category) {
        return { value: category.id, label: category.name };
        })
        console.log(options);

        let rows = this.props.products.map((product, i)=> {
        console.log(this.props.selectValues[i])
        return (
            <tr key={i}>
                <td>{product.name}</td>
                <td>{product.price}</td>
                <td><Select
                options={options} 
                value={this.props.selectValues[i]} 
                // value={product.category_id}
                onChange={this.onProductCategoryChange.bind(this, product, i)}
                /></td>
            </tr>
            )
        });

        return (
        // <h3>MasterCategory : {masterCategoryId}</h3> 
        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th><CategorySelect 
                onChange={this.masterCategoryChange.bind(this)}
                className='masterCategorySelect' 
                categories={this.props.categories}/></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
            <tfoot>
            <tr>

                <td><div className='pull-right'><button onClick={this.handleClick}>Categorize</button></div></td>
            </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
        );
    }
    }


    class CategorySelect extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let options = this.props.categories.map(function (category) {
        return { value: category.id, label: category.name };
        })

        return (
        <Select
            onChange={this.props.onChange}
            options={options} 
            // value={value}
        />
        );
    }
    }

    class SearchBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleFilterTextChange = this.handleFilterTextChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleFilterTextChange(e) {
        this.props.onFilterTextChange(e.target.value);
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <form>
            <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search..."
            value={this.props.filterText}
            onChange={this.handleFilterTextChange}
            />
        </form>
        );
    }
    }


    export default App;
```

Comment: try to add `onBlur={() => {}}` on your select element and I hope that you will get it.

Comment: Thanks Vishal, that hasn't worked